# fuction not returning a list of radio button Reactjs- ReactBootstrap

Tags: arrays, reactjs, settimeout, react-bootstrap

I am working on a dash board, that fetches data from acuity scheduling. 
I am making a form and using a function to get list of radio button:
following array has it, just to clarify. It takes time to get the value in from the API so I have used setTimeout, in the function:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    return timeForID.map( obj => {
      return (<Radio value={obj.date}>{obj.hours}:{obj.mins}</Radio>);
    })
  }, 500)
```

I am getting a blank space in the place of radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of answers in JavaScript out there about working with the event loop and callbacks -- See: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Essentially, your `return` inside of `setTimeout` doesn't go anywhere.

In order to trigger another render in your component, you will have to use `setState`. You can call `setState` after your API call completes -- you shouldn't have to use `setTimeout`. Let's say you're using `fetch` to get the API:

```
fetch(apiUrl).then(response => response.json()).then(dates => setState({ dates }))
```

Now in your render function you can have:

```
{this.state.dates.map(({ date, hours, mins }) => (
  <Radio value={date}>{hours}:{mins}</Radio>
)}
```

Initialize the `dates` property of `state` to an empty array to prevent errors on the initial load.